# What does *& do in c++

Tags: c++

In one of my lectures we had this function that adds elements to a non stl binary three. What does the *& do exactly? I know that & gets the address of a variable and that * allows us to access the value at a particular address. Do they have a different meaning when together? Also if I was to call this function in main, what do I do with the `t` pointer?

```
void add(int n, elem *&t)
 {  
    if (t==NULL)  //ако е достигнат празен указател или дървото е празно  
    {   
        t=new elem;
        t->key=n;  
        t->left=t->right=NULL;      //left и right са NULL, тъй като новият елемент няма наследници  
    }  else      //ако достигнатото място е заето от друг елемент  
    {   
        if (t->key<n) //ако новодобавения елемент е по-голям от текущия, то указателя се измества надясно,извиква се рекурсивно add с указателя вдясно     
            add(n,t->right);   
        else    
        {
            if (t->key>n) //с цел да се елиминират повтарящи се елементи се прави втората проверка      
                add(n,t->left); // извиква се рекурсивно add с указателя вляво 
        }  
    } 
}
```

Here is the structure as well:

```
struct elem 
{ 
    char key; 
    elem *left;  //lqv naslednik
    elem *right; // desen naslednik
}*root=NULL;  // v sluchai che nqma koren
```

Comment: C++ likes to reuse symbols and reserved keywords to mean different things in different context to minimize the number of things it has to reserve. `&` and `*` in types have different meaning from `&` and `*` before an object identifier.

Comment: `*&` does not have any special meaning. It's two separate tokens, `*` followed by `&`.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, it is a part of the `elem*&` function parameter reference type. Used to pass an object of type `elem*` by reference. Pointers are just like any other variables/objects. Passing them by reference allows us to change the pointer value in a function.

The `elem* &t` in your `void add(int n, elem *&t)` signature does not "*get the address of a variable*". It means the type of the function parameter is a reference type. It just so happens it is a pointer reference type in your case.

Do not confuse the *address-of* operator, which is `&` with a reference type signature of `T& param_name`. In your case, the `T` is `elem*`.

It *could* also mean: *dereference the address of an object* if used in the following context:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 123;
    std::cout << *&x;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is a reference type?

Comment: @Ecto A reference type is a type whose object is an alias for the existing object in memory. Changes made to the object of a reference type actually change the object it refers to. It's another name for the existing object. And that name needs to be of reference type.

Comment: so if I have let's say `int x = 0; func(x); cout << x;` and I have `func(x) { x++; }` then 0 will be printed, but if I have `func(&x) { x++; }` 1 will be printed?

Comment: @Ecto I encourage you to post the new question on this subject.